# Need help creating a POST method in salesforce to consume an API

Tags: post, salesforce, mulesoft, salesforce-service-cloud

I need to integrate Salesforce with Mulesoft consuming an API.
when an Account is created, I need to consume an API using a POST method where I should send the next request in JSON using apex classes:

Method: POST
URL: '/Account/CreateAccount/'

Also I got all the information that I need in the account.

```json
{
  "account": {
    "bpCodeParent": "",
    "name": "Clinica Padre",
    "phone": "(760)756-77768",
    "boardMember": "yes",
    "boardMemberShip": "TBD"
  },
  "payment": {
    "territorio": "SEA Distribution",
    "paymentTerms": "Net 30 Days"
  },
  "credit": {
    "creditLimit": "10000",
    "currency": "USD",
    "tender": "yes/NO"
  },
  "contacts": [
    {
      "firstName": "contact",
      "lastName ": "lastContactName",
      "email": "mail@mail.com",
      "contactType": "persona"
    },
    {
      "firstName": "contact2",
      "lastName ": "lastContactName2",
      "email": "mail@mail.com2",
      "contactType": "persona"
    }
  ],
  "adressess": [
    {
      "city": "ciudad",
      "postalCode": "3333",
      "street": "aadd",
      "country": "Argentina",
      "countryISO": "AR",
      "stateProvince": "Cordoba",
      "addressType": "shipping"
    },
    {
      "city": "city2",
      "postalCode": "23333",
      "street": "dds",
      "country": "Argentina",
      "countryISO": "AR",
      "stateProvince": "Cordoba",
      "addressType": "billing"
    }
  ],
  "childAccounts": []
}
```

I know how to trigger the class but I don't how to serialize the JSON and send the request.

Comment: Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
 What issue are you having creating the request? Which Mule connector are you using? Please share the code and configuration you have.

Comment: Are you trying to call a MuleSoft API from Apex? Can you share the Apex code you have so far please